# tortoisesvn refuses to connect to TFS server via svn bridge

Tags: svn, tfs, tortoisesvn, svnbridge

I use svn bridge to connect to a tfs server with tortoiseSVN. I need to use another computer as well for the same purpose.

The problem is while on one computer the url i write in tortoise svn, http://localhost:portNo/serverName/place, works fine and i can to commit, repo browse, etc, on the other comp i get the following error.

In SVNBridge ErrorList i get;

```
Could not find server url in the url (http://localhost:portNo/). Not Valid when using RequestBasePathParser

System.InvalidOperationException: Could not find server url in the url (http://localhost:portNo/). Not Valid when using RequestBasePathParser
 at SvnBridge.PathParsing.PathParserServerAndProjectInPath.GetUrlFromReuest(Uri requestURL)
 at...
```

In tortoiseSVN i get,

```
  Server sent unexpected return value(500 Internal Server Error) in response to PROPFIND request for '/'
```

Something very straightforward is wrong but i'm clueless.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you're only using SVNBridge so that you can use Tortoise SVN, it's worth noting that you can get shell integration into Team Foundation Server directly, which may mean that you don't need to use SVNBridge at all.

The [Team Foundation Server Power Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb980963) include Windows Shell Extensions that will provide tortoise-like functionality.